# Different solutions of Landau-Stuart equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I consider the followin Landau-Stuart equation,
$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \omega A - \frac{\lambda}{2}\left|A\right|^2A,\quad\omega\in\mathbb{C},\,\lambda>0,$$
where $A$ is the complex amplitude and $\omega=i\omega_0+\Omega$. I would like to study all the possible solutions of this equation.

To do it, I use polar representation of $A$, $A=R\exp(i\phi)$ and write down
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\omega_0,\quad \frac{dR}{dt}=\left(\Omega-\frac{\lambda}{2}R^2\right)R,$$
where the first equation is not interesting. I am interested in the specific case $\Omega=\lambda/2$, so
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{\lambda}{2}\left(1-R^2\right)R.$$
It is easy to solve this equation and write down the explicit solution $R=R(t)$ with a given initial condition. Indeed, let $R^2=Q$, so
$$\frac{dQ}{(1-Q)Q}=\lambda dt,$$
$$\frac{dQ}{Q}-\frac{dQ}{1-Q}=\lambda dt,$$
$$\ln Q - \ln (1-Q)=\lambda t - \lambda t_0,$$
where $t_0$ can be determined from the initial conditions. Next,
$$\ln Q - \ln (1-Q) = 2\text{arctanh}\,Q,$$
$$R(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1+\tanh[\lambda(t-t_0)]\right)^{1/2}.$$
There is one more way (noticed by K.defaoite and also mentioned in wiki): the eq. becomes linear for $P=R^{-2}$,
$$\frac{dP}{dt}=-\frac{2}{R^3}\frac{dR}{dt}\rightarrow \frac{dP}{dt}=\lambda-\lambda P,$$
which has the solution
$$P(t) = 1+ \exp(-\lambda t)P(0)\rightarrow R(t)=\left(1+e^{-\lambda t}(R(0)^{-2}-1)\right)^{-1/2}$$

However, I have a vague feeling that there are more different solutions.

I have searched the literature but almost all papers are devoted to consideration of the more complicated Ginzburg-Landau equation (with spatial derivatives). Can anyone recommend the relevant references?

Comment: The equation is linear in the variable $R^{-2}$.